# Convert dictionary in pandas' column to dictionary value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas' DataFrame that has a dictionary as the value in one of the columns e.g.

```
    A    B
1   x   {u'count': 3}
2   y   {u'count': 2}
```

Is there a way to convert the elements in the B column to just the dictionary value in a single operation other than iterating through the entire DataFrame?

So the Dataframe would appear like:

```
     A    B
1    x    3
2    y    2
```

Comment: Your `B` column doesn't look like it contains dictionaries-- there aren't any braces.  Are they really dictionaries, or is it simply a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `apply` on 'B' and pass a lambda which just accesses the single key in the dict:

```
In [83]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['x','y'], 'B':[{'count':3}, {'count':2}]})
df
Out[83]:
   A             B
0  x  {'count': 3}
1  y  {'count': 2}
In [84]:

df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: x['count'])
df
Out[84]:
   A  B
0  x  3
1  y  2
```

*EDIT**

I think you may have missing values `NaN` which is why you get that error, you can mask the df to ignore the rows with missing values:

```
In [88]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['w','x','y','z'], 'B':[np.NaN, {'count':3}, {'count':2}, np.NaN]})
df
Out[88]:
   A             B
0  w           NaN
1  x  {'count': 3}
2  y  {'count': 2}
3  z           NaN

In [89]:

df.loc[df['B'].notnull(), 'B'] = df.loc[df['B'].notnull(), 'B'].apply(lambda x: x.get('count'))
df
Out[89]:
   A    B
0  w  NaN
1  x    3
2  y    2
3  z  NaN
```

You then have to decide what to do about the missing values, you can replace them by calling `fillna`:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].fillna(0)
```

Comment: This does seem to be the correct solution to the problem. I tried this with my data however and I get this error.  TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Well I can't guess what your real data actually looks like, can you post into your question representative data and code to reproduce the problem. 1 question do you have `NaN` values in that column if so I'll update my answer

Comment: Or you could shorten that to `df.get(key, fillval)` if your fill value is constant.

Comment: @smci that will raise an `AttributeError` as there is no dict when there is a `NaN` value which is why you need to filter the rows first